# Create extra functional and related checkboxes in woocomerce register form and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created 2 checkboxes in the register form whose data is saved as the user's meta data when it is registered, it happens that I need to add those same fields in the checkout, the question is, how can I implement the same functionality of these fields in the checkout and that they validate if they have already been selected or not

here is what i tried to implement the fields and validating on both pages but it doesn't work

```
function registration_custom_checkboxes()
{
    return apply_filters('woocommerce_forms_field', array(
        'age_ckeck' => array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __("Soy mayor de 18", "woocommerce"),
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'permission_ckeck' => array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __("Le doy permiso de usar mis datos", "woocommerce"),
            'required' => true,
        )
    ));
}

//Display checkboxes in Registration form
add_action('woocommerce_register_form', 'add_registration_custom_checkboxes', 15);
//Display checkboxes in checkout
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_registration_custom_checkboxes', 16);
function add_registration_custom_checkboxes()
{ ?>
    <div class="checkboxes-container">
        <?php foreach (registration_custom_checkboxes() as $field_key => $field_args) { ?>
            <div class="checkbox-container">
                <?php woocommerce_form_field($field_key, $field_args); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

//Validation for mandatory checkboxes in Registration form
add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'registration_custom_checkboxes_validation', 10, 3);
//Validation for mandatory checkboxes in Chekout
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'registration_custom_checkboxes_validation', 11, 4);
function registration_custom_checkboxes_validation($username, $email, $validation_errors)
{
    $fields = registration_custom_checkboxes();
    foreach (array_keys($fields) as $field_key) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$field_key])) {
            if ($field_key === 'age_ckeck') {
                $validation_errors->add($field_key . '_error', __("You need to approve that your are at leats 18 years old.", "woocommerce"));
            } else {
                $validation_errors->add($field_key . '_error', __("You have to allow us to use your data.", "woocommerce"));
            }
        }
    }
    return $validation_errors;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not using this `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook the correct way. there are no params in this hooks so it will give you `Fatal error:`. check code below

```
function registration_custom_checkboxes(){
    return apply_filters('woocommerce_forms_field', array(
        'age_ckeck' => array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __("Soy mayor de 18", "woocommerce"),
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'permission_ckeck' => array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __("Le doy permiso de usar mis datos", "woocommerce"),
            'required' => true,
        )
    ));
}

//Display checkboxes in Registration form
add_action('woocommerce_register_form', 'add_registration_custom_checkboxes', 15);
//Display checkboxes in checkout
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_registration_custom_checkboxes', 16);
function add_registration_custom_checkboxes(){ ?>
    <div class="checkboxes-container">
        <?php foreach (registration_custom_checkboxes() as $field_key => $field_args) { ?>
            <div class="checkbox-container">
                <?php woocommerce_form_field($field_key, $field_args); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'registration_custom_checkboxes_validation_for_registration', 10, 3);
function registration_custom_checkboxes_validation_for_registration($username, $email, $validation_errors){
    $fields = registration_custom_checkboxes();
    foreach (array_keys($fields) as $field_key) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$field_key])) {
            if ($field_key === 'age_ckeck') {
                $validation_errors->add($field_key . '_error', __("You need to approve that your are at leats 18 years old.", "woocommerce"));
            } else {
                $validation_errors->add($field_key . '_error', __("You have to allow us to use your data.", "woocommerce"));
            }
        }
    }
    return $validation_errors;
}

//Validation for mandatory checkboxes in Chekout
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'registration_custom_checkboxes_validation_for_checkout');
function registration_custom_checkboxes_validation_for_checkout(){
    $fields = registration_custom_checkboxes();
    foreach (array_keys($fields) as $field_key) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$field_key])) {
            if ($field_key === 'age_ckeck') {
                wc_add_notice( __("You need to approve that your are at leats 18 years old.", "woocommerce"), 'error' );
            } elseif( $field_key === 'permission_ckeck' ) {
                wc_add_notice( __("You have to allow us to use your data.", "woocommerce"), 'error' );
            }else{
                // nothing to do here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and works.

[image]